# Debian 11 seems to forgot about multiple adapters and LAN communication?

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet, lan, bullseye

I've been using Debian 10 (buster) XFCE most of the time but had to switch to 11 (bullseye) with GNOME.

With Debian 10 it was no issue to have 2 network adapters running for local purposes without internet.
How was I doing it ?

ip addr add 10.0.0.5/24 dev adapter1
ip addr add 10.0.0.6/24 dev adapter2

After these commands you make adapter1 and 2 in the same network so they can talk to each other.
But Debian 11 does not like that at all ! After 1 minute of working it deletes those ip statements and
shows GNOME notification "Activation of network connection failed".

How am I supposed to tell GNOME or debian (from whichever comes the problem) that it shouldn't bother nor
delete any of my created iproute2 statements ?

On the GNOME networking tab I can safely say that you cannot enable 2 adapters at once which is weird as it wants you to connect just one.

Thanks

I'm expecting adapters to talk to each other without debian or GNOME cutting the communication as it was in Debian 10.

Comment: Your question is not about programming. And I use Debian in one of my router (with many ports), so .. it is not a problem. Probably it is a configuration error (and to talk between interfaces, you should add a route). But you are in the wrong site

Comment: I disagree. In 2012 it was only stackoverflow for everthing and including networking. Now you have all bunch of sites for every category which is totally useless. A good programmer is as well as network admin.

Comment: You can disagree, but people must answer questions. If it takes too much time to filter out which question I'll answer, I'll go away. And you are wrong about other sites. I see the same names here and on other sites (on specific topic): very common. You are just making this site useless. Unix and Linux stack exchange is very useful for such questions. And a good programmer has many roles, doesn't mean all roles must be there. Management, user interface, maths, user interface, work environment, security, etc. (and jokes, traveling, commuting, etc.) (and news: local, technical, global, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analyzing.
Using the iproute2 commands I wrote earlier was working ok for debian 10 but not for debian 11 as currently you have to configure everything from GNOME networking tab.
After that it works as usual.